# Drupal - How to display the list of new fields created from CCK on home page

Tags: php, drupal, cck

I'm building a freelance job site using d6. I've created a new content type called "Freelance Jobs" using CCK which contains various fields such as Job Description, Skills, Start Date, End Date etc.

I want to display the most recent jobs on front page in a listing manners as it is displayed on most job sites.

Following is an example of listing I want to display on home page

Job Title 1
Job Description.......
Skills: PHP, Drupal....
View Details

Job Title 2
Job Description.......
Skills: PHP, Drupal....
View Details

Simple question, how to do it?
Do I need to tweak theme file or I can do it from the Admin by using blocks/regions etc.?

Do I need to create a view to display above details?

Tx.

Answer (score 1):

I think a [view](http://drupal.org/project/views) is your best bet. It is pretty much designed to do what you need.